# What is the view controller structure in a split-view application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am confused as to how I am supposed to be using a split-view application. Can someone please explain the basic application structure? Thanks.

e.g. Why is there a nav controller and detail view controller under the split view controller